# Caching Dynamic GD Image

Tags: php, caching, gd

How would I cache a image that may change every few minutes so it is only generated, lets say, once a hour?

I was told something like this?

```
                header('Content-type: image/png');
                header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800");
                header("Pragma: private");
                header("Expires: " . date(DATE_RFC822,strtotime(" 1 hour")));
```

But it does update with every change, which I'm not sure if that mean it's not caching or changes overwrite the cache?

I tried looking through some other topics but they didn't address my specific issue, or linked to dead pages.

Comment: Caching like this is on a per client basis as well, it wont be cached for someone that never visited the site before.  I would save the image as a file, then the next time it is generated check the file mTime and either regenerate the file or serve the current one. A bigger problem is that a clients browser may catch an old version of the file and wont see it after it is changed, to get by this include the mTime in the filename (img src ) like path/file.jpg?12345 where 12345 is the timestamp.

Comment: That sounds like a solid plan. Thanks. I already was aware of a user not having a cache which is where the generation comes in. Just wasn't sure how to ensure it's not blown up with renders.

Comment: Saving the image as a file is a perfectly valid from of caching it, this is for an image that would be recreated because of changes.  Browser or client side caching is a different topic.  It's almost impossible to not cache it client side, some browsers will ignore the headers.  Wordpress uses the same idea of including version numbers in CSS and JS files to prevent / refresh client caches.

Comment: Yeah, I don't care what the browser does, as long as my server doesn't have unnecessary renders. From monitoring the system, I can get a 5-25% increase in CPU from a single render. I may have to even set up a separate box to handle it if it gets to frequent.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix If you'd like to write up a quick answer and example/explanation you gave me I'll accept it cause it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend SLIR (Smart Lencioni Image Resizer).  It's found here:

https://github.com/lencioni/SLIR

Among other *wonderful* abilities (on the fly/dynamic resizing, auto-crop, etc.), it caches all rendered images for the length of time you provide in its config file.

Comment: Unfortunately it will not for for the highly customized and layered image this is producing. This has nothing to do with thumbnails.

Comment: I understand that; or, at least, didn't suggest thumbnails.

SLIR caches images by default, regardless of render size, and monitors filemtime to catch changes and re-render into its cache.

Comment: Thanks. I get that, but it is reinventing the wheel when it comes to the dynamism of this script. For example, there is no definitive time limit when the user is active on the site, it updates whenever the info provided updates.